# Parse non-standard date format like "+0yyyyMMdd"

Tags: java, parsing, date, format

I Have Date, that comes to our system in format ***+0yyyyMMdd***

For instance 12 March,2011 is ***+020110312***

For now it's definitely **+** symbol and one **0** before Date, but in future it may be more than one **zeros**,e.g. ***+000020110312***

Is it possible to parse it with standard Java *java.text.DateFormat.parse(String source)*?

Or I should write custom parsing method?

Thank you.

Comment: why not parse a substring of the last 8 characters?

Comment: That looks like an ancient packed decimal date format.  The zero made the number of digits odd, so it would pack into 5 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `+0` prefix is a constant, then you can just quote it using singlequotes.

```
String string = "+020110312";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("'+0'yyyyMMdd").parse(string);
System.out.println(date); // Sat Mar 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2011
```

(outcome is correct as per my timezone)

Note that months are represented by `MM` not `mm`. The `mm` represents minutes. Using `mm` for months would corrupt the parsing outcome.

#### See also:

- [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

---

**Update**: since that seem to vary in the future *"but in future it may be more than one zeros"*, you can better consider to substring the last 8 characters.

```
String string = "+020110312";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(string.substring(string.length() - 8));
System.out.println(date); // Sat Mar 12 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2011
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess the +0 is a timezone indicator, so you can try:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("ZyyyyddMM")
```

Alas, this doesn't work immediately.

In order to make it work, get a substring from `0` to `length - 8` and expand it to be four digits to meet the RFC for the timezone. See [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "+020110312"` :/

Answer (score 0):

I would substring the last 8 chars from your representation and then parse it. (I am not sure if you can safely avoid it)

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the date portion using SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
df.parse("20110312");
```

But you would need to strip off the "+000" prefix.